# Adding variable inside Code igniter post variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables, post

I am working with a dynamic form where its fields are attached to the dynamic variables as shown below.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label><?php echo display('name'); ?> *</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input name="<?php echo "firstname".$seat_list_arr[$i];?>" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="First Name" id="name" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('firstname'); ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input name="<?php echo "lastname".$seat_list_arr[$i];?>" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('lastname'); ?>" id="lastname">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
```

MY QUESTION is how to access these dynamic form names by using the post method in code igniter.

```
 'firstname'=> $this->input->post("firstname".$seat_list_arr[$i]),
 'lastname'=> $this->input->post("lastname".$seat_list_arr[$i]),
```

I tried this method but the post method reads nothing.

I will appreciate your help thank you in advance.

Comment: could you please explain where and how `$i`gets defined? Please edit that information in your question!

Comment: $i was a variable controlling the loop to an array $seat_list_arr eg $seat_list_arr = {H1, H2, H3}. so $i was initialized as "0" so as to loop the assignment of variable to hold posted data.

Answer (score 0):

why do not use names as array ?

for example in view `<input name="firstname[?<php echo $seat_list_arr[$i]] ?>"`

then use it as a normal post variable in the controller. by the code `$this->input->post('firstname');` it will return an array to you that you can use a foreach loop to determine exact index you want.

as @ViChel said we need to find how do you work on **$i** and **$seat_list_arr** by the way I hope this would help you